# How do i store My text file data into a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures

## How do you store my Comma seperate file in a vector structure

Hello so i have a file called FILE.txt which has data like this

```
Date,ID,ArrivalTime,DepatureTime
12/02/2022,BDF 021,12:30:20,_
13/02/2022,FSD 213,10:20:30,12:30:20
```

etc I have a vector called `vector<vehicle> vehic(100);`
I want to store it in the vector such that it will be the date will be stored, ID etc

### Function for adding vechicles

So i add vehicles using a function

```
int static totalvehicle=0,totalcar=0,totalamt=0,i=0;
void vehicle::addVehicle()
{

      vehicle *v = new vehicle;
      cin.ignore();
      cout<<"Enter vehicle number : ";
      std::getline(cin, v->id);
      cout<<"Enter arrival time in hours minutes and seconds : ";
      cin>>v->arrive.hh>>v->arrive.col1>>v->arrive.mm>>v->arrive.col2>>v->arrive.ss;
      cout<<"Enter date in day month and year: ";
      cin>>v->dt.day>>v->dt.sym1>>v->dt.month>>v->dt.sym2>>v->dt.year;

      vehic.at(i).id=v->pltno;
      vehic.at(i).arrive.hh=v->arrive.hh;
      vehic.at(i).arrive.mm=v->arrive.mm;
      vehic.at(i).arrive.ss=v->arrive.ss;
      vehic.at(i).dt.day=v->dt.day;
      vehic.at(i).dt.month=v->dt.month;
      vehic.at(i).dt.year=v->dt.year;
}
```

I would like to store it in the same structure as i added them using this function how would i do so please help??

Comment: Note: Don't `ignore` before a `getline` just in case a previous operation left junk in the stream. Sooner or later you'll have a path to the `getline` without that junk and wind up discarding data you needed. Place the `ignore` after the operation that left the junk and you'll never go wrong.

Comment: Note: Don't dynamically allocate an variable unless you need it to outlive the current scope or need polymorphic behaviour. `vehicle *v = new vehicle;` is a leak waiting to happen. And it does happen because `v` is not returned from the function or `delete`ed. Instead either `vehicle v;` and get an automatic allocation or (better in this case) read directly into a reference to `vehic.at(i)` (`vehicle &v = vehic.at(i);`). and lose the copying code at the end of the function.

Comment: OMG, search the internet for "C++ read file CSV".  There are a plethora of questions and examples for CSV files on the internet.  ALWAYS search the internet before posting to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the route to go is to model a row (not the title row) with a structure, and overload `operator>>` for reading an instance.

```
struct Vehicle_Info
{
    std::string    m_date;
    std::string    m_id;
    std::string    m_arrival_time;
    std::string    m_departure_time;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Vehicle_Info& vi);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Vehicle_Info& vi)
{
    std::getline(input, vi.m_date, ',');
    std::getline(input, vi.m_id, ',');
    std::getline(input, vi.m_arrival_time, ',');
    std::getline(input, vi.m_departure_time);
    return input;
}
```

Your input code could look like this:

```
std::vector<Vehicle_Info> database;
Vehicle_Info vi;
while (data_file >> vi)
{
    database.push_back(vi);
}
```

Simple.  Due to the overloaded `operator>>` for the `Vehicle_Info` class.

Comment: I would create date and time classes and overload `operator>>` for them; but that's just me.  You may find an appropriate Date and Time classes in the C++ libraries.

Comment: error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'const char [9]' and 'Vehicle_Info') --- I get this error when i run the input code you provided